# Sending e-mail via Gmail using SwiftMailer

Tags: php, email, slim, swiftmailer

I'm using Slim PHP framework and trying to send e-mail via Gmail.
The problem is when I am sending the e-mail, it will cause "Slim Application Error."

```
$mailer->send($message);
```

Here is my function to send the e-mail

```
function send_email($email)
{
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 587,'tls')
        ->setUsername('pandala61@gmail.com')
        ->setPassword('yourpassword');

    $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);


    // Create a message
    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Test mail')
        ->setFrom(array('from_email@gmail.com' => 'SENDER'))
        ->setTo(array('To_email@gmail.com'))
        ->setBody("Hello, test send mail");

    // Send the message
    $mailer->send($message);

}
```

Comment: What error does it throw?

Comment: Tutorial showing how to configure and send email with Swiftmailer. http://sgeek.org/send-email-attachment-using-swiftmailer-symfony/

Answer (score 0):

Before you use it, you must prepare your gmail account to do it: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/2461835?hl=en
Initializing:
    `// Create Transport. You can use it in directly in routes.php (not good practice), in your config.php file is best.
    $transport = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance()
        ->setHost('smtp.gmail.com')
        ->setPort(465)
        ->setEncryption('ssl')
        ->setUsername('emailat@gmail.com')
        ->setPassword('passw')
        ;`

```
    // Create Mailer instance with our Transport. To be ready to call it.

$mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transport);
</code>
Using: (Where you need to use it. eg: in UserController.php , you can use it.
<code>

    $message = Swift_Message::newInstance()
                    ->setSubject('Email from contact form')
                    ->setFrom(array('email@email.com'=> 'Me'))
                    ->setTo(array('youremail@email.com' => 'You'))
                    ->setBody("I am sending you an email from contact form");

$result = $mailer->send($message);


    // Print the results, 1 = message sent!
    print($result);
</code>
```